# как корректно работать с CSproj в VS2019 если нет SLN в Git ( /плач )

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git, visual-studio-code

да дурак ( но уже в истерике!!, меня видимо гугл забанил!!)
     //подкиньте хоть идей как это загуглить

- когда пишем dotnet new *** не создаётся .sln (это норма)
- проект заливается в git-hub
- студия 2019 хочет солюшен (если с другой
  машины работать)

какой корректный способ работы? какая методология(что ли) должна быть?

Comment: 1) Создать пустой солюшен 2) Добавить туда проекты ?

Comment: @tym32167 это понятно, но это же через Ж как-то. должен же быть способ. ну должны были мелкософт это сделать! чтоб автоматически, мышкой клац клац

Comment: а чем вышеописанный способ плох? можно открыть csproj студией и нажать Save All она предложит сохранить sln

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, дык это ж два действия. Нужно одно!